# couldn't save table in azure databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks

During saving dataframe to tables in Azure Databricks I get error,

```
val employeesDf = Seq(
("Rafferty", Some(31)), ("Jones", Some(33)), ("Heisenberg", Some(33)), 
("Robinson", Some(34)), ("Smith", Some(34)), ("Williams", null)
 ).toDF("LastName","DepartmentID").write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("employ    ees_table")
```

---

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Table
>   "partition_keys" has been specified with a primary-key to include
>   column "TBL_ID" but this column is not found in the table. Please
>   check your  column specification. <div
>   class="ansiout"> at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:549)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createTable(ObjectStore.java:719)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor441.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:108)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.createTable(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1294)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor439.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown
>   Source) ...

Additionally, I am also getting an error during run an example notebook from databricks, in which create tables from path on dbfs

```
%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diamonds;

CREATE TABLE diamonds
USING csv
OPTIONS (path "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data- 
001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", header "true")
```

---

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Table
>   "partition_keys" has been specified with a primary-key to include
>   column "TBL_ID" but this column is not found in the table. Please
>   check your  column specification.    at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:549)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createTable(ObjectStore.java:719)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor441.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:108)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.createTable(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1294)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor439.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:558)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:547)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.createTable(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:613)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:528)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:322)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$retryLocked$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$retryLocked$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.synchronizeOnObject(HiveClientImpl.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.createTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(PoolingHiveClient.scala:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(PoolingHiveClient.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.withHiveClient(PoolingHiveClient.scala:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.createTable(PoolingHiveClient.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.saveTableIntoHive(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:554)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveExternalCatalog$$createDataSourceTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$withClient$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveExternalCatalog$$maybeSynchronized(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$withClient$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:139)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:345)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:331)
>     at
>   com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.createTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:349)
>     at
>   com.databricks.sql.DatabricksSessionCatalog.createTable(DatabricksSessionCatalog.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:81)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3424)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3419)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3419)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:205)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:89)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:696)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:707)     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:87)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)  at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:33)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:136)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:323)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:303)
>     at
>   com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:235)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)   at
>   com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:230)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:47)
>     at
>   com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:268)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:47)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:303)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:591)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:591)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:586)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:477)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:544)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:383)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:330)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:216)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
>   Table "partition_keys" has been specified with a primary-key to
>   include column "TBL_ID" but this column is not found in the table.
>   Please check your  column specification.
>   org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Table
>   "partition_keys" has been specified with a primary-key to include
>   column "TBL_ID" but this column is not found in the table. Please
>   check your  column specification.    at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.ElementContainerTable.applyUserPrimaryKeySpecification(ElementContainerTable.java:217)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.CollectionTable.initialize(CollectionTable.java:240)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.initializeClassTables(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3283)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3185)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2841)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:122)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.addClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1605)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:954)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:679)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2045)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1365)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3827)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.setIdentity(JDOStateManager.java:2571)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForPersistentNew(JDOStateManager.java:513)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:232)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectProviderForPersistentNew(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1414)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2218)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2065)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1913)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:727)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createTable(ObjectStore.java:719)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor441.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:108)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.createTable(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1294)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor439.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:558)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:547)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.createTable(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:613)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:528)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:322)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$retryLocked$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$retryLocked$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.synchronizeOnObject(HiveClientImpl.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.createTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(PoolingHiveClient.scala:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(PoolingHiveClient.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.withHiveClient(PoolingHiveClient.scala:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.createTable(PoolingHiveClient.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.saveTableIntoHive(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:554)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveExternalCatalog$$createDataSourceTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$withClient$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveExternalCatalog$$maybeSynchronized(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$withClient$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:139)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:345)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:331)
>     at
>   com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.createTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:349)
>     at
>   com.databricks.sql.DatabricksSessionCatalog.createTable(DatabricksSessionCatalog.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:81)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3424)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3419)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3419)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:205)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:89)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:696)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:707)     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:87)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)  at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:33)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:136)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:323)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:303)
>     at
>   com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:235)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)   at
>   com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:230)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:47)
>     at
>   com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:268)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:47)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:303)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:591)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:591)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:586)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:477)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:544)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:383)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:330)
>     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:216)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) );

Comment: How did you solve this issue. I have exp the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to run the same query without any issue.

[image]

This issue looks strange. For a deeper investigation and immediate assistance on this issue, if you have a support plan you may file a support ticket.

For more details, refer ["Azure Databricks Quickstart guide](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/getting-started/quick-start.html)".

Comment: After several days, I restarted my cluster and everything started working in normal way

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Comment: I am exp the exactly same issue

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to incorrect configuration of the external metastore